# ERROR: Initialization failure: Cannot create configuration

Tags: cloudbees

i'm trying to get CouldBees working. Heres the error i get when im running:
C:\cloudbees-sdk-1.5.0>bees init --proxyHost=localhost --proxyPort=8008  (or 8080)

> You have not created a CloudBees configuration profile, let's create
>   one now... Enter your default CloudBees API end point [us | eu]: eu
>   Enter your CloudBees account email address: abs@abs.com
>   Enter your CloudBees account password: Jul 18, 2013 1:32:09 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing
>   request: Connection refused: connect Jul 18, 2013 1:32:09 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: Retrying request Jul 18, 2013 1:32:10 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing
>   request: Connection refused: connect Jul 18, 2013 1:32:10 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: Retrying request Jul 18, 2013 1:32:11 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing
>   request: Connection refused: connect Jul 18, 2013 1:32:11 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: Retrying request
>
> ERROR: Initialization failure: Cannot create configuration

Can anyone read out what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SDK can't establish Internet connections to the CloudBees website.  If you are running behind a proxy, you will need to use proxy flags to connect.

```
bees init --proxyHost=YOUR_PROXY_HOST --proxyPort=YOUR_PROXY_PORT
```

This is covered in the CloudBees SDK docs: [Running behind a proxy](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK#HRunningbehindaproxy)

Answer (score 0):

It helps, to set the system time exactly to six hours ago (US-time).
Also cloudbees documentation sais, that You should create on your file system (under Windows7) c:\Users\Your_User.bees\bees.config file, which contains following line (if you want to call cloudbbees eu server):

> bees.api.url=https\://api-eu.cloudbees.com/api>

but actually it didn't help in my case (maybe outdated version)